# HTML hide scrollbars without disabling scrolling functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to hide the vertical scrollbar on my website (without disable scrolling). I tried to achieve this by css, but i haven't good result, either the scrolling functionality was disabled, too, or the vertical scrollbar was still there... 
I know that this question was already asked several times, but I never found an answer! I want to hide every scrollbar on my side, so in every element, also in the entire body

Comment: pls let me know your css sample

Comment: Why should anybody want that? Scrollbars do have a certain purpose, they let the user know that an area is scrollable. If you hide the scrollbars whithout disabling scrolling, I would call this low software quality.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you have only two options with CSS:

Enables scrolling:

```
container { overflow:auto; /*or scroll*/ }
```

Disables scrolling and hides scrollbars:

```
container { overflow:hidden }
```

But you need either one of these instead:

```
container { overflow:hidden-scroll; } /* scroll but no scrollbars */
container { overflow:scroll-indicator; } /* iphone alike scroll 
                                            indicators, only on hover */
```

`hidden-scroll` and `scroll-indicator` values are supported only by [Sciter](http://www.terrainformatica.com/sciter/main.whtm) so far but not by conventional browsers.